# Is there any Whatsapp API for ASP.NET MVC on .NET 4.5 or any alternatives?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-4.5, whatsapp, whatsapi, whatsapp-cloud-api

I need some help with Whatsapp API for my ASP.NET MVC web application, running on .NET 4.5.

Currently I'm using a SMS service to send messages to my users & students. I want to switch to any app like Whatsapp to send messages.